Doubt regarding Newton's 3rd Law for asymmetrical discs
Consider two diagonally halved cylindrical discs connected at center with two rods such that they form a cylinder when joined together (Image 1). The rods are connected to a central motor. The center of motor is at origin in $x,y,z$ axes (Image 2). When the motor starts it tries to rotate these discs against each other in $x-z$ plane.
If the discs were simple symmetrical cylinders it would follow that these two discs will rotate at the same rate but in opposite direction, with the whole system stable at the origin as the center of the system is also their center of mass.
 
Let us consider the discs are transparent and a dot inside each of these discs mark their center of mass. Moreover the outer face of each of the discs makes an angle w.r.t. $x,y,z$ axis. During one complete cycle (before the setup returns to this initial position again):
Q1: How would position of the dots (representing the center of mass) change w.r.t. $x, y, z$ axis during the cycle.
Q2: How would the angle that outer face of each disc makes w.r.t. $x, y, z$ axis change during the cycle.
Q3: How would the position of the motor i.e. geometric center which also represents the center of mass of the system w.r.t. $x, y, z$ axis change during the cycle.
I am looking for a plot w.r.t. the $x,y,z$ axis for each of these.
P.S. We are assuming no other forces or factors (like friction, thermal losses, gravity etc.) but just this idealized case.

When you say $x-z$ plane do you really mean the motor tries to rotate each object around the z axis? That is about the line through their centers? Other than that, have you tried to analyze the situation at all, like say figuring out the moment of inertia tensor (if you are familiar with that) for each half of the object?

I think you meant y axis? The motor (at the center) tries to rotate the discs in the horizontal plane i.e. around vertical axis of rotation (i.e. y axis) - i hope that is clear. I have not as I am struggling to see how to proceed since most of the cases are symmetric as its been ages since school and I have forgotten much of it.

@stack.tarandeep You should show the coordinate system on you diagram to avoid confusion.

Are you asking whether the system wobbles around the center of mass, say, as the sections rotate?

Yes but more. I am asking how the position and orientation of the 2 individual discs, motor and the whole system looks like w.r.t. the $x, y, z$ axis at any point in time as the motor moves. I presume that it would have some cyclical nature i.e. after some $N$ 360 degrees rotations by the motor gears the system will be back to its original configuration (as in image 1) but the rest I am unclear about.

To provide reference we can assume, initially the face of each disc has 0 degrees angle w.r.t. $x, z$ plane. Moreover initially, the line that connects the center of the face to the point of contact with the rod coincides with the y axis for each disc.

I see, well the motion you mean and what I mean are the same since I would have put the axis of this device along a vertical z axis as a standard practice (I don't consider the y axis as vertical motion typically). But I digress, have you considered replacing the objects with their center of mass points as an approximation/simplified problem?

@Triatticus Thanks. sorry for the confusion. I am trying to think through how it will work but I am lost: The center of mass of each disc individually will be at some angle w.r.t. the y axis: for the top disc on the left of y axis and for the bottom disc on the right. An for the combined system (with the motor at center) the center of mass will be at origin. but I am not sure how to proceed with the problem further.

This problem is not very trivial due to the complexity of the inertia tensors of the two shapes and the fact that they change with time. I would first consider tackling the somewhat simpler problem where the two shapes are replaced with point masses at their individual centers of mass.

@VincentThacker Can you please suggest the place for the problem you are mentioning and its step by step solved solution that I can go through and understand (layman here)..

@stack.tarandeep Sorry, I wasn't very clear in my previous comment. I don't know of any book where this problem is addressed, so you'll have to search around yourself. All I'm suggesting is to try a simpler case first, where instead of having the two shapes, you have two identical point masses attached at identical distances from the motor, with identical perpendicular offsets from the motor axis. You will find from some basic non-mathematical analysis that even in this simpler case, the angular momenta of the components change in a wobbly manner.

@stack.tarandeep Also, unfortunately, this site isn't the best place to get others to do problems for you, rather it is mainly for conceptual questions...

The rotation will look like any other rotation.  As you describe the motor configuration, it cannot be anything but the obvious rotation.
However, it looks like the motor/rod is driven through the geometric center of the cylinder, not the center of mass.  The center of mass of each piece is on the tall side of each asymmetric part.  As you counter-rotate the two parts, there will be some times where the heavy side of both parts is on the same side.   Because there are no external forces, the center of mass cannot move.  As such, the motor will appear to rotate, driven to one side or the other.
It would be very similar to a vibrator in a phone or game controller, except in those cases one mounts the motor such that it cannot move with respect to the phone/controller body.  Both have an off-center mass.  Yours has two, but the two will move similarly.  This forces the entire phone or controller to move in a circular motion, creating the vibration.


Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.
